# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Opening Error

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I installed SQL Server Management Studio and it worked fine. After that I updated my Visual Studio from 2010 to 2013 Express edition, now it is not working with this error message :

> Cannot find one or more components. Please re install the application

I re-installed it but still same issue. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I just solved the issue :
SSMS depends on VS 2010 and by uninstalling it this error occurred.

- There is a folder named 1033_enu in my server installation pakage
- Inside that i found a folder VSS i.e Visual studio shell
- and inside that VVS setup.
  i just run this setup and it solved the problem for me. Thank you

Comment: For me this package is located as : 
\SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU_2\1033_ENU_LP\redist\VisualStudioShell\VSSetup

Comment: Also tried this. Completely unistall SQL server and install again. Nothing!

Comment: I downloaded VSIsoShell.exe but could not install it. When i deep dive in to error logs the reason is newer version of visual studio exists on the system. I uninstalled vs2017 community then installation of VSIsoShell is successful

Answer (score 112):

## The SQL Server 2014 Management Studio answer

SSMS 2014 relies upon the Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Shell (Isolated) Redistributable Package.  If this is uninstalled, SSMS will produce the error message 'Cannot find one or more components. Please re install the application'.  This can be corrected by:

1. Reinstalling the VS 2010 Shell from here: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/isolated-shell/
2. Try opening SSMS again.  If it *still* gives the error, then:
3. Run Repair in SQL Server (2014) Setup

## The SQL Server 2016 Management Studio answer

SSMS 2016 relies upon the Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Shell (Isolated) Redistributable Package.  If this is uninstalled, SSMS will produce the error message 'Cannot find one or more components. Please re install the application'.  This can be corrected by reinstalling VS 2015 or by installing the Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Shell (Isolated) Redistributable Package.

Comment: And make sure that the default installation path is NOT changed.

Comment: If you are cleaning up via Programs and Features of old Visual Studio software do not remove Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Reditributable - x86 .... , MS Visual C++ 2010, and MS VS 2010 Shell (Isolated) that is what caused this to break on me.

Comment: Does not fix for SSMS 2016 March Preview

Comment: Sweet, only needed to perform step 1 in the proposed solution. SOLVED.

For context I had my SSMS 2012 installation melt down after uninstalling an older Visual Studio. Fixed now apparently.

Comment: This appears to no longer work for the latest versions. I have the 2016 July update and following these steps no longer works.

Comment: I just had this issue with SSMS 2016 (rel 16.3).  I tried the repair option on the installer which had no effect.  I came across the following post which suggested to remove a registry key (HKCU\Software\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\13.0_Config) which solved the issue for me.  Not sure why repair didn't do this if it's a known issue,

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/634911c8-8c85-46c7-aa9d-00c842cefb52/

Comment: @MarkG, You should really consider posting the solution from your comment as an answer. It worked for SSMS 2016 (16.3). Other suggestions to fix this issue didn't work at all in my case.

Comment: SSMS 2012 also depends on VS2010 Shell.

Comment: @MarkG this worked for me on SSMS 2016 as well (reinstall/repair didn't help).

Comment: How to get Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Shell (Isolated) Redistributable Package?

Comment: SSMS 2017 also uses the VS2015 (Isolated) Shell.  A good 'ol repair from  "Programs and Features" control panel (look for "Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Shell (Isolated)" ) resolved the problem for me, without downloading anything!

Comment: @MarkG deleting the registry key also worked for SSMS 2017 but 14.0_Config.

Comment: I downloaded VSIsoShell.exe and installed it and MS SQL Server Management Studio 2014 worked.

Comment: I downloaded VSIsoShell.exe but could not install it. When i deep dive in to error logs the reason is newer version of visual studio exists on the system. I uninstalled vs2017 community then installation of VSIsoShell is successful

Comment: Reinstalling the Visual Studio 2010 Shell solved my problem with SSMS 2014. After trying numerous places, I ultimately found a downloadable that worked to reinstall the VS 2010 shell here: https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/9/3/1939AD78-F8E8-4336-83F3-E2470F422C62/VSIsoShell.exe.

Answer (score 21):

For SSMS 2016 (at least v16.5.3) delete the following folder from the registry and restart the app:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\13.0_Config
```

Comment: This solution just worked for me with SSMS 17. Key to delete was respectively 14.0_Config.

Comment: deleteting 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\' worked for me

Comment: Thank you! Deleting 14.0_Config worked for me using SSMS 17.9.1 & VS Community 2017.

Comment: This worked for me. Delete any folder in regedit which end with "_config"

Answer (score 9):

### **The SQL Server 2017 Management Studio answer**

SSMS 17.1 also depends on Visual Studio 2015 shell (isolated). I had to repair the Shell to get SSMS to work. In case someone is looking for VS 2015 Shell: [LINK](http://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/downloads/vs-shells/)

If you cannot find the installer using the above link, the SSMS 17.x installer [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?WT.mc_id=-blog-scottha) includes the VS 2015 Shell.

Scott Hanselman has also conveniently included a link to every (>= 2008 R2) Express and SSMS version here: [LINK](http://downloadsqlserverexpress.com/)

Comment: Shell repair didn't work for me with SSMS 17.9. I've got two warnings that the installation cannot continue because newer product versions are already installed (C++ redistributables 14.0.23029).

Comment: Installing SSMS 17.9.1 fixed the issue for me.

Comment: No amount of reinstalling SSMS17.x or 18.x fixed it for me... until I did the repair install of VS2015 Shell. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In order to free up some space on my disk, I had uninstalled some programs after which I started getting this error.

I followed all the solutions here, but it didn't fix my problem.

For me, after installing the Visual Studio Shell, I had to delete a key from my registry by following the steps [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/634911c8-8c85-46c7-aa9d-00c842cefb52/cannot-find-one-or-more-components-please-reinstall-the-application-when-starting-ssms-2016?forum=sqltools). Then finally my SSMS started working again.

Quoting from the page:

> 1. Start regedit.exe
> 2. Go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio
> 3. Delete 13.0_Config
> 4. Restart ssms.exe

Comment: Tried all other solutions this is the only one that works. Upgrade from Win 7 to Win 10 caused 2K8R2 to stop working, had to install 2K12 and ran into the above error. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I had this same issue happen to me when I was stripping my machine of everything `Microsoft` to refresh my system with 2016-2017 versions of `Microsoft` products.. First time doing this so I deleted the `Visual Studio` shell and installed everything 2017 except the `2015 VS` shell (not sure if 2017 is out), here was my mistake.

To solve.. first off, make sure you have the `Visual Studio Isolated Shell` installed. Certain versions of `SSMS` need a specific version of the shell. My situation called for `VS Shell 2015` with my `SSMS 2016`..

Just installing and repairing the `Shell` didn't help me completely fix the error. What helped me was deleting a key from my `Registry Editor`. Run the command `regedit` from anywhere on your machine and then find:

```
'HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Microsoft/SQL Server Management Studio/*shellversion*_Config'
```

Right-click and delete this folder/key. For `SSMS 2016` I deleted `13.0_Config..` Right away I was able to open `SSMS` as usual.

Answer (score 3):

All the answers here didn't work for me (SQL Server 2014).

What worked was:

1) Uninstall the Visual Studio 2010 Shell using official installer (**not via Programs and Features**). The file **VSIsoShell.exe** can be downloaded here: 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1366

2) Once uninstalled, run SQL Server Installation and hit **Repair**

Answer (score 1):

Try running SSMS as administrator! After repairing & re-installing multiple components, in the end it was just the security level of my account.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem with SQL Management Studio 2016 by running the VS setup, selecting "Modify" and then installing Extensibility Tools Update 3. After that I just ran SQL Management Studio 2016 and it reset VS Isolated Shell

Answer (score 1):

For all versions of SQL Server, this can be fixed safely with no loss of data including any plugins that may be installed and their data.

This is a common bug, and the solution in all versions of SQL Server is to repair the 'Microsoft Visual Studio 20xx Shell (Isolated)' program installation, which takes about 30 minutes to run unattended.

To perform the repair, please complete the following steps:

1. Close all instances of Visual Studio.
2. Press the Windows key.
3. Type 'Programs'.
4. Click 'Add or Remove Programs' from the list that appears.
5. Type 'Shell' into the Search box that appears.
6. Click 'Microsoft Visual Studio 20xx Shell (Isolated)'*
7. Click Modify (If greyed out then click Uninstall).
8. In the window that appears, click 'Repair'.
9. Wait 30mins or so for repair to complete.
10. Restart machine.

'Microsoft Visual Studio 20xx Shell (Isolated)' will now be repaired and SQL Server Management Studio should open as normal.

* If there are multiple version(s) of 'Microsoft Visual Studio 20xx Shell (Isolated)' installed, then repair the latest one first, working backwards through versions until the correct program is repaired. Be sure to make a note of the version that fixed your version of SQL Server for future reference as it will not change until smss or vs is upgraded.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue after using the custom [VS2015 uninstallation tool](https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller) and installing the VS2017. Repair or reinstall of the SSMS 17.3 does not solve the issue.

To resolve it open the Windows Control panel, select the Programs and Features. Select the `Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Shell (Isolated)` from the list and click Change. Then click Repair in the VS setup window. On setup completed ignor the warnings about some newer components already installed. Click Close and thats it! SSMS starts perfect! Hope this save someone's time.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded VSIsoShell.exe but could not install it. When i deep dive in to error logs the reason is newer version of visual studio exists on the system. I uninstalled vs2017 community then installation of VSIsoShell is successful

Answer (score 0):

Download and Install Visual Studio 2015 Isolated Shell.

You can further read the details of this Redistributable Package from [Microsoft Visual Studio 
 2015 Redistributable Package](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb685691.aspx)

You can further Download this Package from [this link](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Survey/ThankYou.aspx?SurveyID=17717&ProgramID=8963)

After Installing this package, Please run SSMS for SQL SERVER 2016. It actually works for me!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case none of the registry edits or software reinstalls mentioned in the other answers work for you, I was having this issue due to anti-virus. In this case it was Crowdstrike, but others can cause it as well.

Try disabling your AV to test, and if that's the culprit, put an exception in for SSMS 2014/2016.

Answer (score 0):

None of above solutions worked for me , Link in the accepted answer is not working.

So I tried repairing MSSQL 2014 from Setup , This will install Visual Studio Shell which it depends on.

```
SQL Server Installation Center -> Maintenance -> Repair -> Select the Instance
```

Next , You will be able to run ssms without an issue.

Hope that works,

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this to work - open up 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\RSConfigTool.exe"
then used the repair tools in there, rather than from the control panel install programs (repair).
This seemed to run through reinstalling of files and afterwards everything worked great! I was tearing my hair out!

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled already existing microsoft visual studio 2010 Shell(isolated) -ENU
Then did repair
To do repair please follow below path : SQL Server Installation Center -> Maintenance -> Repair

Note: None of the above worked for me.This is only worked